# Weird texture in bge

Tags: texturing, game-engine, materials

When I press <kbd>P</kbd> to play my game, my mesh transforms to ugly textures, but when I just view in the viewport the mesh is perfect.

It does not come from normals or from GLSL.

Here is a GIF of my problem
[Problem.gif](http://pix.louiz.org/o/szBeE.gif)

The gif is big (40mb), wait for it to load before viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have semi-transparency enabled. Turn it off.

Other than that you might have a mirror modifier active or mirrored the mesh somehow.